# How to give a method the ability to work with objects from another thread in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I have a library that works by accessing objects on the stage, I need something that the method that I call in another thread can do something on the stage, I will be very grateful for the help.

I am using the Task class

```
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // My method in library
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify Unity objects from outside of the main thread.  So if your task needs to modify a Unity Object, you will need to grab the SynchronizationContext from the main thread and use that to Post or Send work back to the main thread for the actuall unity object modifications and references.

```
// make sure you are on the main thread when you call this next line.
SynchronizationContext mainThreadSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
Task.Run(() => {
    // do heavy work
    // then when you want to modify a unity object or referenc them, you have to delegate the work to run
    // on the main thread.
    mainThreadSyncContext.Post(_ => {
        // async so it does not block and the work will be executed at some point (most likely the next tick)
        // safely reference Unity objects and functions
    }, null);

    mainThreadSyncContext.Send(_ => {
        // synchronous so it will send the the main thread and wait for a return before continuing
        // safely reference Unity objects and functions
    }, null);
});
```